# Does ng-app on HTML element act like an on/off switch?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I'm using Angular 1.6.1. The goal is to click on a list item, and it shows the tab number. This bit of code doesn't work on its own:

```
<ul>
    <li ng-click="tab = 1" >
        Thing 1
    </li>
    <li ng-click="tab = 2" >
        Thing 2
    </li>
</ul>
<p>{{tab}}</p>
```

However, once we add this, it works:

```
<html ng-app="">
</html>
```

And it even works when the `ul` is outside the `ng-app` scope. So:

```
<ul>
    <li ng-click="tab = 1" >
        Thing 1
    </li>
    <li ng-click="tab = 2" >
        Thing 2
    </li>
</ul>
<p>{{tab}}</p>

<html ng-app="">
</html>
```

Does not work when element is a `div`:

```
<div ng-app="">
</div>
```

Am I just mixing up an understanding of some low-level HTML functionality, or how is this working?

Comment: Example #3 is invalid HTML so the browser fixes it by moving the content inside the <html> tags. Right-click anywhere, select "inspect element" and you'll see the "real" HTML structure.

Comment: ng-app is the starting point for the application. angular will ignore ng-XX if the document does not contain an ng-app.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`ng-app`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngApp) bootstraps Angular on your code. You can put it on the `body` tag if you prefer, but your Angular code must be in that block.

I would not say that *"ng-app acts like an on/off switch"*, and **I do not recommend using it like this**.

If you want to "activate/desactivate" some parts of your code, you should use [`ng-if`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngIf) <sub>(or other, it depends of your needs)</sub>.

---

From the examples you provided:

**Example 1**

It does not as Angular is not bootstraped in your application (as explained before)

**Example 2**

It works, as it is the good way to write your code

**Example 3**

It is probably the most strange:
As your document is not well-written and not [HTML valid](https://validator.w3.org/check), your code is **rewritted** by your browser. So:

```
<ul>
  ...
</ul>
<p>{{tab}}</p>

<html ng-app="">
</html>
```

Becomes

```
<html ng-app="">
  <ul>
    ...
  </ul>
  <p>{{tab}}</p>
</html>
```

**Example #4**

It does not work, as your Angular code is not **inside** this div (and it is not rewritted by your browser like Example #3).

Comment: That's not what he's asking. The question is why templating works (seemingly) outside the `ng-app` directive.

Comment: @JJJ is correct--@Mistalis explains the behavior that I expect, but not the behavior that I observe.

Comment: @stephen Get it. I updated my answer to provide an explanation for each code you provided.